# Accessing the choices passed to argument in argparser?

Tags: python, argparse

Is it possible to access the tuple of choices passed to an argument? If so, how do I go about it

for example if I have

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='choose location')
parser.add_argument(
    "--location",
    choices=('here', 'there', 'anywhere')
)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

can I access the tuple `('here', 'there', 'anywhere')`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that `parser.add_argument` actually returns the associated `Action`.  You can pick the choices off of that:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='choose location')
>>> action = parser.add_argument(
...     "--location",
...     choices=('here', 'there', 'anywhere')
... )
>>> action.choices
('here', 'there', 'anywhere')
```

Note that (AFAIK) this isn't documented anywhere and *may* be considered an "implementation detail" and therefore subject to change without notice, etc. etc.

There also isn't any *publicly* accessible way to get at the actions stored on an `ArgumentParser` after they've been added.  I believe that they are available as `parser._actions` if you're willing to go mucking about with implementation details (and assume any risks involved with that)...

---

Your best bet is to probably create a constant for the location choices and then use that in your code:

```
LOCATION_CHOICES = ('here', 'there', 'anywhere')

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='choose location')
parser.add_argument(
    "--location",
    choices=LOCATION_CHOICES
)
args = parser.parse_args()

# Use LOCATION_CHOICES down here...
```

Comment: pfft what's the fun with sticking with the porcelain commands? Lemme have some of that plumbing! ;)

Comment: @AdamSmith -- From what I've seen, `argparse` internals are pretty stable (but don't quote me on that ;-)

Comment: Right. They're stable until they're not and your application (and subsequently the world) crashes unexpectedly when the user enters as an argument `--ritual Iä!_Iä!_Cthulhu_fhtagn!`

Answer (score 2):

There might be a better way, but I don't see any in the documentation. If you know the parser option you should be able to do:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--location", choices=("here", "there", "everywhere"))

storeaction = next(a for a in parser._actions if "--location" in a.option_strings)

storeaction.choices
# ('here', 'there', 'everywhere')
```

As in mgilson's answer, accessing the `_actions` attribute is undocumented and the underscored prefix means "Hey, you probably shouldn't be messing with me." Don't be surprised if this breaks between versions of Python.

Answer (score 1):

On the question of what `add_argument` returns, if you do any testing in an interactive session like `ipython`, the return stares you in the face:

```
In [73]: import argparse
In [74]: parser=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [75]: parser.add_argument('foo',choices=['one','two','three'])
Out[75]: _StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='foo', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=['one', 'two', 'three'], help=None, metavar=None)
In [76]: _.choices
Out[76]: ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Note that other methods like `add_argument_group`, `add_subparsers`, `add_parser`, `add_mutually_exclusive_group` all return objects that can be used.  The fact that `add_argument` is not documented as returning an object is, I think, a documentation oversight.  Usually users don't need to use it, but as a semi-developer I use it all the time.  The documentation for `argparse` is not a formal specification of what the module can or can not do; it is more of an instruction manual, a step up from a tutorial, but clearly not a reference.

The use of `parser._actions` is handy, but a step deeper into the guts.  I have followed nearly all the bug/issues and can't think of any that would trigger a change in this.  There's a big backlog of potential changes, but developers have been reduced to near-immobility over fears of creating backward compatibility issues.  It is easier to change the documentation than to change the functionality of `argparse`.