# Get argparse help message by argument name in Python

Tags: python, argparse

I've got quite complicated script with commands and options for these commands. Also I've got special command which prints help about other commands usage and for it I need to print help for commands options. All commands and options are in argparse so I just need a way to make a kind of this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--some-option', help='Help text')

# I need this to print "Help text":
print(parser.<some_method_to_get_help_by_arg_name>('some_option'))
```

Could anybody help with it?

UPD:
I've seen question [Accessing the choices passed to argument in argparser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460102/accessing-the-choices-passed-to-argument-in-argparser) but it is 5 years old and for  implementation proposed there as far as I understand I will need to make additional data structure which looks weird because all needed content already is stored in argparse object and I could get values by option name, why not help message?

Comment: I don't understand your objection to the earlier answers.  What I wrote 5 years ago is still true.

Comment: The parsed value is accessed by name (`dest`) from the `args` object returned by `parse_args` method.  Your `help` is an attribute of the `Action` object created by the `add_argument` method.  Either retain a reference to that object, or find it in the `parser._actions` list.